# Does Xcode includes unit tests or UI tests when it archives a project or when submitting to Apple/Adhoc?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, archive, adhoc, ui-testing

I am trying to understand if Xcode includes unit tests or UI tests when it archives a project or when submitting to Apple/Adhoc.

I could not find anything online about this subject and would appreciate any help given.

Thanks